# Any file compare tool that matches function names and then compares them instead of line by line comparison?

Tags: text-editor, file-merging

I need to compare two files as .txt or .c or anything.
These files have the same class name and same functions.
But the functions are not in the same order for two classes.

The first file is:

```
class A
{

int subtract (int a, int b){
//some code here
int c=a;
int d=b
return c-d;
}


int add (int a, int b){
//some code here
return a+b;
}

}
```

Second file is:

```
class A
{


int add (int a, int b){
//some code here
return a+b;
}



int subtract (int a, int b){
//some code here
return a-b;
}

}
```

Using notepad++ compare tool or ultracompare tool do not give what I want. They say that

```
subtract is changed to add in line 4
int c=a;
int d=b
return c-d; removed
return a+b; added
```

And much more nonse because they compare line by line, I want some intelligence.

But I want that

```
int add (int a, int b){
//some code here
return a+b;
} is moved to 15. line
```

and 
    in

```
int subtract (int a, int b){
//some code here
return a-b;
}
```

function

```
int c=a;
int d=b
return c-d; removed
return a-b; added
```

Is there any compare tool that does what I want, especially free or cheap?

Comment: I am not sure but did you try Beyond Compare ?

Comment: Beyond Compare doesn't detect moved sections, it will show them differences (inserted/deleted lines). To force two moved sections to compare, right click on a line on the left and select Align With, then left click on a line on the right.

Comment: Not posting this as an answer because it's not free and I've never used it, but https://www.semanticmerge.com/  seems to have a product with a 15 day free trial.